# Injecting Criteria into an sfPropelRoute object

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I have a `Page` object whose uniqueness comes from its `PageDomain`. The schema is configured such that the `page` table contains a `page_domain_id` field to create the relationship. To show a page, I have an `executeShow` action and a custom handler. My route looks like this:

```
page_show:
  url:     /:domain_slug/:slug
  class:   sfPropelRoute
  options:
    model: Page
    type:  object
    method_for_criteria: doSelectByDomain
param:   { module: page, action: show }
requirements:
  sf_method: [get]
```

By way of an example, I might have `/audience/create` and also `/behavior/create`. I need to be able to determine which page is being requested.

The intent of the custom handler (`doSelectByDomain`) is to factor in the `domain_slug` and only retrieve/show a page if its domain is also correct. What I'm finding, though, is that even though a `domain_slug` parameter is available in the action's `$request` parameter, I have no way of getting it to my custom handler so that it can be factored into what's retrieved.

I realize that I can access the `sfContext` object directly from my model, but that's inelegant at best and breaks MVC. I'm not afraid to use it if there's really no better way, but it seems like there must be. Symfony offers a `setListCriteria` method for list routes, but I can't find anything similar for object routes.

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a little venture through the source code got me where I needed to be. It seems that `sfPropelRoute` offers the `method_for_criteria` option, but respects the `method` option of `sfObjectRoute` and uses it instead if it exists. If only `method_for_criteria` exists, then the `sfPropelRoute` class creates a criteria object from the request parameters.

*Except that it doesn't include any parameters that aren't properties of the object.* I understand that there's an argument to be made for that behavior, but in my opinion it's a mistake.

Anyway, the short version is that if you use the `method` option, all parameters are passed (without edit) as an array to the specified handler. If you need request parameters other than those that are properties of the object, this appears to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem completely (I read this for the Propel tag, not the Symfony tag), but is the [Advanced Routing](http://www.symfony-project.org/advent_calendar/2/en) chapter from the Advent Calendar of any help? The code is given for Doctrine, but I guess you can also adapt it for Propel.